# How to get my graph draw larger?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, standalone

I had tried to adjust all the length, but i cannot draw the full length of the graph.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    interval & carT & carD  \\
    1     & 1.2  & 0.1    \\
    2   & 12.8 & 3.8    \\
    3    & 15.5 & 10.4  \\
    4   & 14.0 & 17.3  \\
    5   & 7.9  & 21.1  \\
    6      & 3.0  & 22.3  \\
    7      & 3.0  & 22.3  \\
    8      & 3.0  & 22.3  \\
    9      & 3.0  & 22.3  \\
   10      & 3.0  & 22.3  \\}\mydata

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            bar width=.3cm,
            width=\textwidth,
            height=.8\textwidth,
            legend style={at={(0.5,1)},
                anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={1,2,3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10},
            xtick=data,
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align={vertical},
            ymin=0,ymax=35,
            ylabel={\%},
        ]
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carT]{\mydata};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carD]{\mydata};
        \legend{Trips, Distance}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One really shouldn't use \textheight or \textwidth in standalone. While they are defined, their values are arbitrary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as of topic supplement to [Jānis Lazovskis answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505886/how-to-get-my-graph-draw-larger/505889#505889) with small changes of your code and his image border proposition. Changes are indicated in code by `% <---`.

**Edit:** table `mydata is moved inside`tikzpicture` and a little bit changed

```
\documentclass[margin=1pt]{standalone} % <---
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}              % <---

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{
interval  carT  carD
    1    1.2    0.1
    2    12.8   3.8
    3    15.5  10.4
    4    14.0  17.3
    5    7.9   21.1
    6    3.0   22.3
    7    3.0   22.3
    8    3.0   22.3
    9    3.0   22.3
   10    3.0   22.3
        }\mydata

    \begin{axis}[
    width=\linewidth,
    height=.8\linewidth,
    ybar=0.5mm,         % <--- distance between bars (shift bar)
    bar width=4.4mm,    % <--- width of bars
    legend style={legend columns=-1,
      outer sep=1mm,    % <---
      font=\scriptsize, % <---
      anchor=north,
      at={(0.5,1)},
                  },
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize, inner sep=2pt}, % <---
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ylabel={\%},
    ymin=0, ymax=30,     % <---              
    xtick=data,
    scale only axis,     % <---
        ]
    \addplot table[x=interval,y=carT]{\mydata};
    \addplot table[x=interval,y=carD]{\mydata};
    \legend{Trips, Distance}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Are we able to add in `data table` into bar graph?

Comment: @aan, sorry, I don't understand you. Which table you like to add? Where you like to have this new table? As part of `tikzpicture`?

Comment: @ann, I edit answer. Now table `mydata` is inside of `tikzpicture`. Also the code is slightly improved (to my taste, of course)

Comment: thanks. I mean the `data table` as in this quesitons https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505861/data-table-data-lable-error-bar-gridlines-for-bar-graph-pgfplots

Comment: @ann, as it is now in edited answer?

Comment: thanks. I edited my questions for clearer. Thanks

Comment: @ann, please only one problem per question, What you add now to your question is duplicate to your previous question. If you not agree with this, then please ask new question.

Comment: @Zarki, thanks. Noted. I cancel my previous second question and ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

You can adjust it in the options for `standalone`, by changing the first line of your code to:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={0 0 5pt 0}]{standalone}
```