# How to make the label to move into middle of graph

Tags: graphics, positioning, document-classes

1 How to make the whole diagram alight to my words in my page?
I am using `\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}`

2. How to make the graph label in the center? I had change from `south east` to `east`, but not working.

   `legend style={cells={align=right, font=\small}}, 
   legend pos=north,`

Diagram
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book} 

% \documentclass[tikz,border={10pt 20pt 5pt 5pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
% \pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}   % <---
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{
interval  carT  carD
    1    68    32
    2    94   6
    3    84   16
    4   100    0
    5   100     0
    6   83      17
    7   100     0
    8   100     0
    9   100     0
    10  89      11 
    11  100     0
    12  100     0
    13  100     0
    14  95      5
    15  95      5
    16  84      16
    17  68      32
    18  84      16
    19  95      5   
    20  89      11
        }\mydata

  \begin{axis}[
    width=0.9\linewidth,
    height=.8\linewidth,
    ybar=0.5mm,         % <--- distance between bars (shift bar)
    bar width=2mm,    % <--- width of bars
    % legend style={legend columns=-1,
    %   outer sep=1mm,    % <---
    %   font=\scriptsize, % <---
    %   anchor=south,
    %   at={(1.2,1)},
    %               },
   legend style={cells={align=right, font=\small}}, 
   legend pos=north,                  
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize, inner sep=2pt}, % <---
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ylabel={Classification Accuracy (\%)},
    xlabel={Test Case},
    ymin=0, ymax=100,     % <---              
    xtick=data,
    scale only axis,     % <---
        ]
    \addplot table[x=interval,y=carT]{\mydata};
    \addplot table[x=interval,y=carD]{\mydata};
    \legend{Correct, Incorrect}
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\subsection{The Results}
Testing123 Testing123 Testing123

\end{document}
```

Comment: See my answer on your previous question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505886/how-to-get-my-graph-draw-larger/505892#505892, i.e use the same `axis` preamble. and remove line with ` legend pos=north, ` (which is not supported by `pgfplots`).

Comment: @Zarko. Thanks. It works. I tried `     legend style={legend columns=1,
       outer sep=1mm,    % <---
       font=\scriptsize, % <---
   anchor=south,
   at={(0.92,1.0)},
               },`.Can you expaling the `at={(0.92,1.0)}` meaning? Is it cordinate meaning?

Comment: it define coordinates of the legend position (in relative to diagram: `(1,1)`  is top left corner of the diagram, `(0.5,1)` is top of the diagram, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let mi elaborate my comments. Comments in code indicate changes to your code and its meaning:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}              % <---

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
   \pgfplotstableread{
interval  carT  carD
    1    68     32
    2    94      6
    3    84     16
    4   100      0
    5   100      0
    6    83     17
    7   100      0
    8   100      0
    9   100      0
    10   89     11
    11  100      0
    12  100      0
    13  100      0
    14   95      5
    15   95      5
    16   84     16
    17   68     32
    18   84     16
    19   95      5
    20   89     11
        }\mydata

    \begin{axis}[
    width=\linewidth,   % <---
    height=.8\linewidth,
    ybar=0.3mm,         % distance between bars (shift bar)
    bar width=2.2mm,    % width of bars
    legend style={legend columns=-1,    % <---
      outer sep=1mm,    % define space around legend
      font=\scriptsize, % see if `tiny is better suited 
      anchor=north,     % <---
      at={(0.5,1)},     % coordinate of legend (at top side of diagram)
                  },
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize, inner sep=2pt}, 
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ylabel={\%},
    ymin=0, ymax=120,   % <---
    xmin=0, xmax=21,    % <---
    xtick=data,
    %scale only axis,    
        ]
    \addplot table[x=interval,y=carT]{\mydata};
    \addplot table[x=interval,y=carD]{\mydata};
    \legend{Trips, Distance}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: thanks. I need to try and check what value is the best for ‘pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}’

Comment: @aan, version of `pgfplots` package, which is used in this MWE. 1.16 is temporary the recent one.

Comment: thanks. Do you mean I can change the value of 1.16 to any value that I desired?

Comment: @ann, not necessary. If you will select too old version, it can happen, that it will not work as expected . Version 1.15 will works, however I suggest you to update your `pgfplots` installation.

Comment: thanks. It works very well. Thanks. Last question: I am using overleaf, so it seemed no need `pgfplot` installation. Overleaf only have `pgfplot version 1.15', when i put 1.16, it said no available. but it works

Comment: @ann, version 1.15 should be sufficient, just use this version. Unfortunately in general *Overleaf* has one year old packages ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98020/discussion-between-aan-and-zarko).